# allowPrivilegeEscalation=true and RequiredDropCapabilities=SETUID in Kubernetes/OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

I have read the descriptions of these here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privilege-escalation

And i'm still very confused as to whether these are the same but opposing settings? For instance in OpenShift's `restricted` SCC we have `SETUID` as one of the `RequiredDropCapabilities`. At the same time, in the same SCC, we have `allowPrivilegeEscalation`=true.

Is one disallowing processes to be launched under other users but the other one allowing that?

This is what i read on `allowPrivilegeEscalation`=true:

> This defaults to allowed so as to not break setuid binaries

and for SETUID:

> setuid() sets the effective user ID of the calling process

(from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)

Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1):

A setuid binary is a file that has the 4000 bit flag in its file permissions. While we usually talk about Unix file permissions using just three octal digits (744 or 600, etc), the next the bits are commonly used for suid, sgid, and sticky. A suid executable is automatically setuid()'d to the ID of the owner of the file. This is how tools like sudo work, which require elevated permissions but are run by unprivileged users.

Comment: Thank you. So even though I'm not able to run a process under say root (dropped capability) I may still be able to assume the privileges of root by running an executable that is owned by root and has its setuid set (that's allowPrivilegeEscalation)?